# discrete probability question

Tags: probability, combinatorics

```
    Suppose we randomly choose a byte (8 bits). What is the
 probability that the byte has at least two 1's?
```

Can someone explain why is the answer 247/256 and what formula do you need to do this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subtract from $\dfrac{256}{256}$ the probability of the complement: the probability that the byte has (NO 1's or exactly/only a single 1.)

(1) Probability of zero 1's: $\dfrac 1{2^8} = \dfrac 1{256}$

(1) Probability that the byte has exactly one digit 1 = $8\cdot\dfrac{1}{256}$

$$\dfrac{256}{256} - \left(\dfrac {1}{256} + \dfrac {8}{256}\right) = \dfrac {247}{256}$$

That leaves you with the probability that a byte has two or more $1'$s

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful. Maybe you can take the test for me tomorrow.